I need to get the ResourceGroup and ResourceID of the Associated Azure VM of my DSC node
I have two nodes registered in resourcegroup1 when I run Get-AzAutomationDSCNode.
Both nodes have the same name "Node1" but belong to different resource groups.
Node1 - resourcegroup1
Node1 - resourcegroup2

since they are both registered under the same resourcegroup, how can I get the associated vm of the nodes using powershell so i can know the right one to delete.
The properties of the Get-AzAutomationDscNode does not contain VmResourceID


how can I get the associated vm of the nodes using powershell

Here is the PowerShell script to get the VM names by using automation account nodes.
    $resourceGroupNames = @("RG1", "RG2")
    $automationAccountNames = @("Automate-WUS2", "MM")
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $resourceGroupNames.Length; $i++) {
        $resourceGroupName = $resourceGroupNames[$i]
        $automationAccountName = $automationAccountNames[$i]
    
        $dscNodes = Get-AzAutomationDscNode -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName
    
        foreach ($dscNode in $dscNodes) {
            Write-Host "DSC Node Name: $($dscNode.Name), Resource Group: $resourceGroupName, Automation Account: $automationAccountName"
        }
    }

Output:

Updated Script:
You can use below PowerShell script to retrieve the VM resource ID from the DSC nodes configuration.
    $resourceGroupName = "RG_Name"
    $automationAccountName = "Automation_Account"
    
    $dscNodes = Get-AzAutomationDscNode -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName | Select-Object -Unique
    
    foreach ($dscNode in $dscNodes) {
        Write-Host "DSC Node Name in Automation Account : $($dscNode.Name)"
        
        $VMs = Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $dscNode.Name
        
        foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
            Write-Host "Name              : $($VM.Name)"
            Write-Host "ResourceGroupName : $($VM.ResourceGroupName)"
            Write-Host "ResourceId        : $($VM.ResourceId)"
            Write-Host "Location          : $($VM.Location)"
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }

Output:


This doesn't work. There is only one automation account. and the dscnode returns same information for both because they have same names and are registered under the same resource group. Even though the associated Vms are in different resourcegroups.
The resource group name is the same for the nodes so the iteration makes no difference in the output. Thank you for looking into this.

Do you mean VM names are the same as the names in the DSC node output?

correct. same vm names

Hi @Ayandaezekiel, I have updated an answer as per your requirement, check and let me know the status.

It's great to know that it worked for you.
